# Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible /var/www/html/redmine on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: apache, ubuntu-14.04, redmine, symlink, ubuntu-server

Hi I am having this error when I try to access from remote computer to the following path: http://my_ip/redmine.

I did a Symbolic Link from /opt/redmine/redmine-3.2.1 to /var/www/html/redmine.

Then I configure the apache2 config like this:
[image]

But I can not access too.

Then I try to activate the FollowSymLinks into apache2.conf file but still continue with error 403.

At finally I found that I have to give access permissions to /opt/redmine/redmine-3.2.1 I did it with chmod o+x but did not work too.

At the end I tried to give the root path (/) but did not work too.

Some suggestion?

Thanks for your help mates.

PD: Sorry if my english is so bad.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access http://your_ip/redmine make sure that apache root directory is pointing to /var/www/html, because your file is in /var/www/html/redmine.

You need to configure the 000-default.conf file on /etc/apache2/sites-available like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
   Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html
   ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
   CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

#vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Then try to open http://your_ip/redmine. If it still error 403, create a file named redmine.conf in /etc/apache2/sites-available, and configure that file like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
   ServerName redmine
   Options FollowSymLinks
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html/redmine
   ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
   CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Then `chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/redmine`

Answer (score 0):

If your symbol link go to a directory with permissions defined and associated to a user, for example:

```
/var/www/html/my_web -> /home/user_web
```

See if **/home/user_web** has permissions to execute, for example:

```
drwxr-xr-x user user /home/user_web
```